# Hubot Rocket.Chat User Joined

Tags: hubot, rocket.chat

I couldn't find any information on using Hubot with Rocket.Chat to log a Welcome message when a user joins the channel.

I wanted to make a support channel where people who join are then asked what they need help with (a specific subject).

However using:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->

  robot.enter (res) ->
    res.send "insert message here"
```

does not seem to work for me at all.  Any one know how to get a welcome message in Rocket.Chat?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure hubot is connected to your Rocket.Chat instance?

You should check your hubot logs. Have you started hubot with `bin/hubot --adapter rocketchat`?

Then you must also set your environment variables: `ROCKETCHAT_URL`, `ROCKETCHAT_USER`, `ROCKETCHAT_PASSWORD`.

This should be enough to make your hubot run and connect to your instance.

Comment: Yes it is working.  Everything is running and the bot is responding to other things.  But the bot isn't saying anything when a user enters, so the robot.enter command doesn't seem to work.  I read in the documentation that it depends on if the adapter supports it, so I'm guessing that it doesn't and was looking for how to get a workaround.